# Impact about spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Source code:

```
val FILES_MAX_PARTITION_BYTES = SQLConfigBuilder("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes")
  .doc("The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files.")
  .longConf
  .createWithDefault(128 * 1024 * 1024) // parquet.block.size
```

Is there any performance gain on reading when increase/decrease that?

Is it necessary to set 256MB while reading `orc` files?

Furthermore, how to set that correctly